# Records are missing on clicking save button to store ExtJS grid records

Tags: extjs

When I do cancel all changes(button), whatever changes made in `grid` has been reverted. After that when I try to save the records, one row got deleted (which was deleted before doing cancel all changes). Is there any listener to resolve this?

**To delete a record I'm using:**

```
grid.getStore().remove(record);
grid.getView().refresh();
```

**On click of cancel all changes performing below:**

```
var grid= Ext.getCmp(config.id);
grid.getStore().load();
```

Comment: Please post a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have done so far.

Comment: Did you try  grid.getStore().rejectChanges() ?

Comment: grid.getStore().rejectChanges() solved my problem.. thanks.. :)